# How to create an empty array named by variable and use it only by referring to it thru the variable name?

Tags: arrays, variables, powershell, powershell-2.0, named

How to create an empty array named by variable and **use it only by referring to it thru the variable name?**

e.g. array named **empty**

```
$empty = @()

$empty -is [array]
True
```

versus:

```
$arrayname='empty'
${$arrayname}=@()

$empty -is [array]
False
```

**AND**

```
$empty+='hello'
```

versus

```
${$arrayname}+='hello'
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question - can you elaborate?

Comment: me too.! What is your final goal?

Comment: My final goal is to be able to automate creating and modifying arrays. I will have function that updates arrays so I won't have to repeat the similar code e.g. for adding, but i will just run function x arrayname add melon

Comment: Ummm... `$name = @()` creates an empty array, `$name += "foo"` adds an element to the array. I fail to see how you could get any simpler than that.

Comment: Well, imagine that you have to do a list of very similar actions with 100 arrays, then it begs for simplification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want this:

```
$arrayname='empty'

$empty -is [array]
False

Invoke-Expression  "`$$arrayname = @()"

$empty -is [array]
True
```

Comment: Yes, as simple as that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a [PSObject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mediaandmicrocode/archive/2008/11/26/microcode-powershell-scripting-tricks-select-object-note-properties-vs-add-member-script-properties.aspx)

```
$empty = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    ArrayName = "String"
    ArrayValue = @()
} 
$empty.pstypenames.Insert(0,"SuperArray")
// Here you add the generic function to manipulate your array
$empty | Add-Member ScriptProperty Add {$this.ArrayValue} { $this.ArrayValue = $args}
```

The data structure may be optimized to better fit your requirement.